Intersections of ideals and subrings as modules
Let $I\subset\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}[x,y]$ be the ideal:
$$I=⟨5x^2y,5xy^2-k⟩\cap\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}[x,y]$$
Where $\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}[x,y]$ is the ring of symmetric polynomials in two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$, and $k\in\mathbb{Q}$. Since $\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}[x,y]$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, $I$ is an ideal by the intersection of ideals and subrings property. Since $\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}[x,y]$ is noetherian, there is a generating set $\mathrm{Gen}(I)=\{f_1,f_2,...,f_n\}\subset\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}[x,y]$ such that:
$$I=\sum_{i=1}^n⟨f_i⟩$$
But i'm unable to find the elements of $\mathrm{Gen}(I)$. Any help with this matter wiill be appreciated.

By the nullstellensatz, $I\subseteq\mathfrak{m}$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset \mathbb{C}[e_1,e_2]$, where $\{e_1,e_2\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ are the elementary symmetric polynomials in two variables, and hence:
$$\mathfrak{m}=⟨e_1-a_1⟩+⟨e_2-a_2⟩$$
For some $\{a_1,a_2\}\subseteq \mathbb{C}$. Particularly, it must be the case that $\mathrm{Gen}(I)\subset \mathfrak{m}$, which greatly simplifies the problem. It is also worth noticing that the modular law for groups can be applied to $I$ to obtain:
$$I=⟨5(x^2y+xy^2)-k⟩+\left(\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}[x,y]\cap⟨5xy^2⟩\right)$$

$I$ is an ideal of the ring of symmetric polynomials. Not of the ring of all polynomials. Your approach needs to be adjusted accordingly. For example, we need to use the fact that the ring of symmetric polynomials is Noetherian (in fact, it is isomorphic to a polynomial ring in two variables).

What is $k$? (Please add this info.)

Thanks for the corrections. I edited the post accordingly.

What is $\mathbb{Q}_{S_2}$?

@user26857 $\mathbb{Q}{S_2}$ is only specified with relation to the object $\mathbb{Q}{S_2}[x,y]$, where it is defined as the ring of symmetric polynomials in two variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$.

I see. Then I think that this ring is $\mathbb Q[x+y,xy]$.
